# Loop variable and assignment

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, variable-assignment

I'm new in coding and actually learning Javascript.

I'd like to iterate throught alphabet and dynamically set variables and contents in Javascript.
The result should be :

```
var botA = eleve["bot-A-value"];
var botB = eleve["bot-B-value"];
var botC = eleve["bot-C-value"];
```

How would you do that please ? Thanks for your help and sorry if this topic may have already been resolved

Comment: _"How would you do that please ?"_ - not at all. You should use an _array_ or _object_ for something like this, not individual variable names.

Comment: Which `eleve` already is.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers. I've made an array with alphabet and I iterated on it but can't instanciate variables with type before the the variable. "var" seems blocked or something, I can't use it in my for loop.